# change scope property with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why doesn't it work to set the `$scope.blured` within this `setTimeout()` (simulating a post and response)?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/15knxKNY0FNfn9IhqvIR?p=preview)

```
$scope.bluryLines = function(value) {
    $scope.blured = true;

    if (value === '' || value === undefined) {
        console.log('value is empty');
    } else {
        console.log(value);
    }

    //faking a post
    setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.blured = false;
        console.log('log');
    }, 1000);
};
```

pushing the button cleares it right away.

```
$scope.removeOverlay = function() {
    $scope.blured = false;
};
```

Comment: does it log 'log' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` doesn't run a digest. Use the angular [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service instead.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.bluryLines = function(value) {
        $scope.blured = true;

        //faking a post
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.blured = false;
        }, 1000);
    };

});
```